# Extraer array de un método en JavaScript para usarlo fuera

Tags: javascript, array

quiero extraer el array votos y el array partidos para poder usarlo en otro archivo js. Os dejo el código. Mirad los comentarios con mayúsculas para entender lo que pido. No he puesto todo el código porque no es relevante.

**spliter.js**

```
 function readFile(evt) {
    let file = evt.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e) => {
        let lines = parseCSV(e.target.result);
        //ESTOS SON LOS DOS ARRAYS QUE QUIERO SACAR 
        partidos=lines[0];
        votospartido=lines[1];
        console.log(partidos);
        console.log(votospartido);
       
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
```

**funcion.js**

```
function FormularioHondt(formul)
{
    var numpartidos=9;
    var ct; //contador
    var numvotos=Number(formul.votblan.value);
    var numescs=Number(formul.numesc.value);
    var liston=Number(formul.liston.value);
    var nombres=partidos;//AQUI QUIERO UTILIZAR LOS ARRAYS
    var votos=votospartido;
    var esc=new Array();
    var num_min_votos;
    var resultado; 
    var numpartidosok=0;
    var votosok=new Array();
    var nombresok=new Array();
}
```

Comment: Si tus variables _partidos_ y _votopartidos_ son variables locales, debes llamar a tu función `FormularioHondt` dentro de tu método, función, etc y pasarle como parámetros esos dos arrays, por lo que deberías modificar la declaración de tu método `FormularioHondt` para que reciba dos argumentos más (los arreglos). O bien, declarar _partido_ y _votospartido_ como variables globales, las asignas y las pasas como parámetro a `FormularioHondt`

Comment: [Lectura recomendada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244361/can-i-access-variables-from-another-file) en el homónimo en inglés.

Comment: Si el caso es usarlos en otro archivo.js, usa import/export, son fáciles de aprender. Sino, siempre puedes guardar los array en sesionStorage

Comment: Hola, JSR, ¿qué biblioteca le proporciona la función `parseCSV`?, y lo otro es que debes suministrar, al menos, la estructura del archivo CSV. Es decir, se necesita conocer cuántas o cuáles columnas la integran en su defecto. Por otra parte, debes proporcionar el código HTML faltante para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: Por otra parte, te invito a realizar un [tour] para que conozcas cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla.